# subdomain to subfolder on Heroku PHP site?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, heroku

How can I get this domain..

```
   api.somewebsite.com
```

to point to this actual location..

```
   somewebsite.com/api
```

I'm using a simple PHP page on Heroku, with .htaccess file.

I already setup the subdomain with my dns hosting and add a subdomain via heroku cli.

this is what ive tried so far....

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.somewebsite\.com$
   RewriteRule ^ /api [L]
```

and

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.somewebsite\.com$
   RewriteRule .* /api [L]
```

to no avail... the browser is making

```
   api.somewebsomesite.com go to api.somewebsite.com/api
```

I want to take out the subdomain in the ^

how to accomplish this using .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/api%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You're commenting too! And I answered it! :p

Comment: its redirect to the root instead of root/api, but if i put api.somewebsite.com/api it goes where i want it

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.somewebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://somewebsite.com/api [L,R]
```

Comment: this is redirecting api.something.com to something.com, just like ive instructed in the dns hosting. but if i put api.somewebsite.com/api, then it goes where i want it. i want api.somewhere.com to go somewhere.com/api

Comment: Is the `DocumentRoot` same for `api.something.com` and `something.com`?

Comment: i have no access to the apache server its on heroku, but yes in dns hosting they are both point to the same domain/root, something .com

Comment: So `api.somewebsite.com/api` is same as `somewebsite.com/api`?